# Applying Magento CE Patches

Tags: patches, shell

Per the Magento [download page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download), under the patches section

> Please upload the patch into your Magento root directory and run the appropriate SSH command: 
>   For patch files with the file extension `.sh: 
>   sh patch_file_name.sh 
>   Example: sh PATCH_SUPEE-1868_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh

Magento recommends a direct invocation of the `sh` command to run their patch runner.  The file extension of `.sh` supports this as well.

However, if you [look at the top of each patch runner file](http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/ce_patches/PATCH_SUPEE-2631_EE_1.11.0.0_v1.sh), the shebang line points to `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Patch apllying tool template
# v0.1.2
# (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
#
```

The programmer in me wants to trust the source file, but the process wonk wants to obey what's written on the Magento website, the cynic wonders if the patch has been tested against [the differences between bash and sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).

Comment: The patch process should be as simple as .diff files zipped up. `REQUIRED_UTILS='sed patch'` all I see in the `.sh` scripts. The upgrading docs for recent versions reads like stereo instructions, and upgrading shouldn't be that painful.

Comment: I somewhat blindly fetch the patch, chmod +x and run it . (Well I check the contents first) but I run it locally (Mac based dev) so I can git branch and commit to a test branch before deploy.

Comment: @B00MER That's tricky. I agree personally, but for tech savvy but not unix savvy people manually applying patches seems like a step too far.  I can understand the motivations behind a patch installer.

Comment: Just thinking about this again. The shebang lins could be #!/bin/php for example and, sh executes "enough" to read the shebang line and pass the script to the shebang'ed program. On the subject of manual applies, the patch contains the Git Diffs anyway, so you can "easily" apply yourself. But, is there an argument to ask Magento to provide a zip with changed files in only, along side a Patch (which is fine except for Core edits)?

Comment: One more thing. The use of a file extension, other than .txt probably makes it more logical for the less savvy, to avoid having extensionless files floating about the local users file system. I feel bash and sh are interchangeable anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use bash, actually. On line 14 of the patch you explicitly pointed out is this code:

```
if (( $? != 0 )); then
```

`$((` is a [valid arithmetic expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) in XCU sh, but `((` is not.)

On many UNIX-like platforms, however, `/bin/sh` is just a symlink to `/bin/bash`. When invoked with the name `sh`, bash does disable *some* of its POSIXly-unstrict behavior, but not all of it. It's likely that these patches would work fine for bash invoked as sh.

Comment: In this case tho, the script isn't executing under sh, sh is dumping off to the stated shebang line program?

Comment: Actually the kernel is responsible for interpreting the shebang. If you `chmod +x script && ./script` the kernel will attempt to execute the command in the shebang line with the script file as its first or second argument. Depending on the circumstances, there's no guarantee that any shell is involved in that process tree. If you execute `sh` with a script as its argument, however, the shebang line will be ignored.

Comment: So that means I'm following the patch instructions wrong. As they say do sh script but I just do ./script How amusing

Answer (score -2):

In case it helps someone in future, I have used Phpstorm to apply patch and its patch tool is great. It took less than 30 seconds to apply patch without any issues and you can also see and go through the differences the files have.